# Turning CSV Single-Column data into Interaction Matrix

Tags: r, csv, matrix, social-networking

Apologies if this has been addressed, I do not see it on here.

I am trying to take CSV data and turn it into a interaction matrix in R or Excel.

Basically, I have authors of each paper in a row, and need to consolidate each row into an interaction. For example:

```
Current: 
1. A; B; C; D
2. E; F; C
3.  A; G; D; C

Need: 
   A B C D E F G
A    1 2 2     1
B  1   1 1
C  2 1   2 1 1 1
D  2 1 2 1     1
E      1     1
F      1   1
G  1   1       1
```

Any assistance in automating this from the current CSV would be most helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what your input data looks like, but let's assume you are able to read in your data to a list where each entry is a vector of authors like so:

```
papers<-list(
    P1=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
    P2=c("E", "F", "C"),
    P3=c("A", "G", "D", "C")
)
```

First I take each paper and merge the author name with the paper name

```
apl <- lapply(names(papers), function(x) cbind(paper=x,author=papers[[x]]))
```

Then i combine all those parts into one large data.frame

```
dapl <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, apl))
```

Then I tabulate the counts of authors per paper

```
tap <- table(dapl)
```

And then I take the cross product to get the interactions with each author

```
crossprod(tap)
```

which seems to be the matrix you are after. Of couse you could do this all in line line

```
crossprod(table(data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
    lapply(names(papers), function(x) cbind(paper=x,author=papers[[x]])))))) 

#       author
# author A B C D E F G
#      A 2 1 2 2 0 0 1
#      B 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
#      C 2 1 3 2 1 1 1
#      D 2 1 2 2 0 0 1
#      E 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
#      F 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
#      G 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

The only difference is that there are no blank entries. They are filled with zeros on the off-diagonals and total paper count for each author on the main diagonal.

Here's one way to create the paper's list if your data is formatted exactly as in your sample. (Here I use a `textConnection`, but you can just as easily use the file name)

```
tt<-textConnection("1. Rashid, Umer; Ahmad, Junaid; Yunus, Robiah; Ibrahim, Muhammad; Masood, Hassan; Syam, Azhari Muhammad
2. Hussain, Raja Azadar; Badshah, Amin; Tahir, Muhammad Nawaz; Tamoor-ul- Hassan; Bano, Asghari 
3. Shahida, Shabnam; Ali, Akbar; Khan, Muhammad Haleem
4. Khan, Mumtaz; Jabbar, T.; Asif, M.; Anjum, M. I.; Dilband, M.; Khan, K.; Jabbar, A.; Arshed, W."
)

lines<-readLines(tt)
close(tt) #not needed if you supply file name to readLines

#split paper number and list of authors
spt<-strsplit(lines,"(?<=\\d)\\.\\s+","",perl=T)

#split authors
papers <- strsplit(sapply(spt, '[', 2), ";\\s+")
#add fake paper names
names(papers) <- paste("P", sapply(spt, '[',1), sep="")
```

Comment: Very helpful. Wondering if you have thoughts on automating the first part. I have 800 articles and roughly 1200 authors.

Comment: @user3653552 I have no idea what your input data looks like exactly, therefore i cannot make a specific recommendation.

Comment: I have 780 rows similar to this. 
1. Rashid, Umer; Ahmad, Junaid; Yunus, Robiah; Ibrahim, Muhammad; Masood, Hassan; Syam, Azhari Muhammad
2.Hussain, Raja Azadar; Badshah, Amin; Tahir, Muhammad Nawaz; Tamoor-ul- Hassan; Bano, Asghari
3. Shahida, Shabnam; Ali, Akbar; Khan, Muhammad Haleem
4. Khan, Mumtaz; Jabbar, T.; Asif, M.; Anjum, M. I.; Dilband, M.; Khan, K.; Jabbar, A.; Arshed, W.
5. Khalid, M.; Mushtaq, A.
6. Ahmad, Ishaq; Usman, M.; Naqvi, S. Rabab; Iqbal, Javed; Bo, Lu; Long, Yan; Dee, C. F.; Baig, Aslam
7. Ajaz, M.; Suleymanov, M. K.; Khan, K. H.; Zaman, A.; Younis, H.; Rahman, A.

Comment: @user3653552 I've added info about how to read in that data at the end of my answer